# php code to count column values and add to date column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
coupon = 700,701,702,703

startdate  = 25-02-2015
```

Now I need to count value of coupon column.

**For example** - Now there are 4 values present inside coupon column.

Now I Need When I search 700 , then it select startdate and add +1 months in startdate boz 700 is in 1st position and generate output like below

**for ex-** 25-03-2015

When I search 701 then it get startdate and +2 months in startdate boz 701 is in 2nd position and generate output like below

**for ex-** 25-04-2015

When I search 702 then it get startdate and +3 months boz 702 is in 3rd  position like wise for all.

**for ex-** 25-05-2015

and return result in `generateddate` variable for inserting in database.

```
 <?php
    if(!empty($_GET['q'])) {
       $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=circulation_scheme_prepaid', 'root', '');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $q = $_GET['q'];
        $result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM receipt_entry WHERE coupon  = :coupon'); 
        $result->execute(array(':coupon' => "$q"));    
        $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $info = array();
        foreach($data as $row) {

        $coupon = $row['coupon'];                           
        $startingdate = $row['startingdate'];

        $temp = explode(',', $coupon); 
        $key = array_search($search_word, $temp);

        $inc_month = $key + 1;
        $generateddate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+$inc_month months", strtotime($startingdate )));
         $info[] = array('date' =>$generateddate );
        }
        echo json_encode($info);    
    }
    ?>



 <!--AUTO POPULATE TEXTBOX ON COMBOBOX CHANGED EVENT START -->
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementByName("cityname").value="";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) 
        {           
            document.getElementById("generateddate").value = data[i].date;
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","coupondata.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


<input type="text" name="coupon" id="coupon"  onChange="showUser(this.value)"  class="field size4" />
```

Comment: Bad schema == bad code.Please read an article on database design (especially normalization) before proceeding further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, after exploding :

```
$coupon = $row['coupon'];                           
$startingdate = $row['startingdate'];

$temp = explode(',', $coupon); 
$key = array_search($search_word, $temp);

$inc_month = $key + 1;
$generateddate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+$inc_month months", strtotime($startingdate )));
```

Comment: sir i edit my post plz read what i want ...i need to add position no in startdate...

Comment: and also suggest how to implement i an new in php...If you do this i am grateful to you....

Comment: Replace your code old segment with mine and let me know.. try print the variables for clarification.

Comment: sir i replace my code with your code but not getting values in textbox...plz see i change code in my post...